The pytorch model was converted to the wrong onnx format
the question is when I use torch.onnx.export to convert a pytorch model to onnx type,the inputs of model are treat as a constant.
here is my code:
model.py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchcrf import CRF
from ASR.BiLstm.config import CFG

class BiLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cfg = CFG()
        self.embedding_layer = nn.Embedding(
            self.cfg.token_size, self.cfg.hidden_size)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=self.cfg.hidden_size,
            hidden_size=self.cfg.hidden_size,
            batch_first=True,
            bidirectional=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.cfg.hidden_size * 2, self.cfg.entity_type_num)
        self.crf_layer = CRFLayer(num_tags=self.cfg.entity_type_num)
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(0.5)

    def forward(
            self,
            x: torch.Tensor,
            senquence_length: torch.Tensor,
            label: torch.Tensor = None):
        x = self.embedding_layer(x)
        output_sequence, (_, _) = self.lstm(x)  # [batch,seq_len,hidden_size*2]
        lstm_features = self.drop(output_sequence)
        lstm_logits = self.fc(lstm_features)
        mask = self.crf_layer.create_mask(
            senquence_length, max_length=lstm_logits.shape[1])
        if label is not None:
            loss = -self.crf_layer.crf(emissions=lstm_logits,
                                       tags=label, mask=mask)
            return loss
        else:
            output = self.crf_layer.crf.decode(
                emissions=lstm_logits, mask=mask)
            # 将列表转换为张量
            output_tensor = torch.tensor(output, dtype=torch.long)
            return output_tensor


class CRFLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_tags):
        super().__init__()
        self.cfg = CFG()
        self.crf = CRF(num_tags=num_tags, batch_first=True)

    def create_mask(self, sequence_length: torch.Tensor, max_length: int):
        batch_size = sequence_length.shape[0]
        arange = torch.arange(max_length).unsqueeze(0).expand(batch_size, -1)
        # 如果你的模型是在GPU上运行，确保arange也在相同的设备上
        if self.cfg.device == 'cuda':
            arange = arange.to(sequence_length.device)
        # 将范围张量扩展成 [batch_size, max_sequence_length] 的形状，
        # 并与每个序列的实际长度进行比较，小于实际长度的位置为True，否则为False
        mask = arange < sequence_length.unsqueeze(1)
        return mask

utils.py:
def export_onnx(model, dataset):
    '''
    导出onnx
    '''
    cfg = CFG()
    model.eval()
    input_sequence, sequence_length = dataset.transfer_query('画个本环')
    inputs = (input_sequence, sequence_length)

    # 使用torch.jit.trace进行追踪处理
    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, inputs)

    torch.onnx.export(
        model=traced_model,
        args=inputs,
        f='BiLstm_model.onnx',
        input_names=['input_sequence', 'sequence_length'],
        output_names=['decode_result'],
        dynamic_axes={
            'input_sequence': {0: 'batch_size'},
            'sequence_length': {0: 'batch_size'},
            'decode_result': {0: 'batch_size'}
        },
        do_constant_folding=True,
        opset_version=15
    )
    try:
        onnx.checker.check_model(r'BiLstm_model.onnx')
        netron.start(r'BiLstm_model.onnx')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # train()
    model = BiLSTM()
    checkpoint = torch.load(
        r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\项目\ASR\interaction\ASR\BiLstm\checkpoints\checkpoint_4.pth')
    # 加载模型的state_dict
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
    dataset = MyData()
    export_onnx(model, dataset)

in utils.py's function "export_onnx",both input_sequence, sequence_length are torch.tensor type.
and shape of "input_sequence" is torch.size([1,20]),shape of sequence_length is torch.size([1]).
And here is the model graph generated by 'netron.start'  :
enter image description here
My python version is 3.11. torch version is 2.3.1+cu121. onnx version is 1.16.1.
I searched the Internet for my problem, but did not find the same problem.
I want to know what I can do to properly convert the model to onnx format
